# Sandboxed child process launced with NSTask fails silently

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, sandbox, nstask

I'm building an OS X app that contains a command-line executable. The app calls the executable, passing along a filename that was chosen by the user, and grabs the output with a pipe. The code for doing this looks something like this:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
let binaryPath = bundle.URLForResource("myBundledBinary", withExtension: nil)
let task = NSUserUnixTask(URL: binaryPath!, error: nil)
let stdout = NSPipe()
let stderr = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = stdout.fileHandleForWriting
task.standardError = stderr.fileHandleForWriting

task.executeWithArguments([filename], completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
    let output = stdout.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let error = stderr.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let outputString = NSString(data: output, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? ""
    let errorReport = NSString(data: error, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? ""
    handler([outputString, errorReport], nil)
})
```

This works fine, until I try to sandbox the app. When this code runs in the sandboxed app, the task seems to complete, but without any output on either stdout or stderr (both `outputString` and `errorReport` are empty strings). No error is generated (the `error` is always nil), and no console output happens.

My app has these entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Which gives the app executable this signature:

```
Executable=/path/to/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName
Identifier=com.thoughtbot.AppName
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=1509 flags=0x0(none) hashes=66+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=fe53fcb996ac55360ecf9cb86be414432e254f24
Signature size=8512
Authority=Developer ID Application: ZZZZ, Inc
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=2015-01-12 14:19:51
Info.plist entries=24
TeamIdentifier=0123456789
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=30
Internal requirements count=2 size=732
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The bundled binary has these entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
<true/>
```

I'm using codesign manually to sign the bundled binary with those entitlements, resulting in this signature:

```
Executable=/path/to/myBundledBinary
Identifier=com.foo.AppName.myBundledBinary
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=6335 flags=0x0(none) hashes=307+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=4d9c009084ff8a821fcb1c55f83a4661ed2bc32b
Signature size=8512
Authority=Developer ID Application: ZZZZ, Inc
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=2015-01-12 14:19:44
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=0123456789
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=2 size=300
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've read Apple's documentation on sandboxing, as well as a variety of existing SO questions, all of which seem to suggest that this should work. The fact that I'm not even getting any errors, just silent failure, is really bothersome.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the underlaying NSUserUnixTask code checks if the path is executable. Executable by sandbox rules, not just filesystem executable flag.
So you need to share with use the location of the helper app you wanna run. You can test this yourself with C access function, see man ACCESS(2).